# Toggling Background-Color with Radio Btns works! But the Cookie does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, toggle

Am working with Cookies for the first time.. Have included the jquery cookie script.. Am looking to have these toggle-btns apply a site-wide background-color change that is maintained from page to page.

The toggle btns html looks like this:

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default lightBtn">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="light"> Light
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default darkBtn">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="dark"> Dark
    </label>
  </div>
```

And the working JQuery looks like this:

```
   $('.lightBtn').click( function() {
      var color = "white";
      $("body").removeClass("black").addClass(color);
      $(".modal-content").removeClass("black").addClass(color);
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("black").addClass(color);
   });
   $('.darkBtn').click( function() {
      var color = "black";
      $("body").removeClass("white").addClass(color);
      $(".modal-content").removeClass("white").addClass(color);
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("white").addClass(color);
   });
});
```

But the cookie code that I iterated on from another stack post looks like this:

```
$( function() {
   $('.lightBtn').click( function() {
      var color = "white";
      $("body").removeClass("black").addClass(color);
      $(".modal-content").removeClass("black").addClass(color);
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("black").addClass(color);
      createCookie("color", color);
      return false;
   });
   $('.darkBtn').click( function() {
      var color = "black";
      $("body").removeClass("white").addClass(color);
      $(".modal-content").removeClass("white").addClass(color);
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("white").addClass(color);
      createCookie("color", color);
      return false;
   });

    if (readCookie("color") != null && readCookie("color") != "white") {
      $("body").removeClass("black").addClass(readCookie("color"));
      $(".modal-content").removeClass("black").addClass(readCookie("color"));
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("black").addClass(readCookie("color"));
    }
    else if {
    if (readCookie("color") != null && readCookie("color") != "black") {
      $("body").removeClass("white").addClass(readCookie("color"));
      $(".modal-content").removeClass("white").addClass(readCookie("color"));
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("white").addClass(readCookie("color"));
    }
    else {
      $("body").removeClass("black").addClass("white");
      $(".modal-content").removeClass("black").addClass("white");
      $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("black").addClass("white");
    }

});

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: You have typo remove `if {` from line `else if { if (readCookie("color")`

Comment: Nice! Good find.. Thanks for that

Comment: You should read cookie only once. There is too much `readCookie("color")`

Comment: @Satpal could you provide an example? Removing the `readCookie("color")` after the `if .. {` and after the `else if .. {` does not work..

Comment: I have posted code as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, This is refactored code

```
var cookieColor = readCookie("color");
var removeColor = "";
if(cookieColor == null){
    cookieColor = "white";
    removeColor = "black";      
} else if(cookieColor != 'white'){
    removeColor = "black";
} else if(cookieColor != 'black'){
    removeColor = "white";
}

$("body").removeClass(removeColor).addClass(cookieColor);
$(".modal-content").removeClass(removeColor).addClass(cookieColor);
$(".dropdown-menu").removeClass(removeColor).addClass(cookieColor);
```